# how to resolve this error while installing express in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, visual-studio-code

C:\Users\MOM\Desktop\projects\See You>npm install --save express

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"eslint":"5.12.1",'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\MOM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-16T10_08_46_594Z-debug.log

*the above-mentioned code was the error I'm getting please help me, guys.

Comment: please Share the package.json file content

Comment: It looks like your `package.json` has a simple JSON error. Have you put it into a [linting tool](https://jsonlint.com) to verify it's fine?